# unregister/delete all child nodes of a div tag in dojo

Tags: javascript, dom, html, dojo

I have a div tag, lets say "mydivTag"

It has a child node under it with an ID of "childID"

I want to delete/unregister/whatever "childID" and then recreate a *different* node with the same ID, "childID"

How do I achieve removal of the first object with ID "childID" so that when I make my new object with that same ID, I don't get an error about there already being a widget registered with the ID "childID"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

have you tried something like

```
dojo.query("#childID", mydivTag).orphan()
```

then

```
dojo.create("div", {id: "childID"}, mydivTag)
```

These are just shorthand for DOM APIs like `removeChild` and `createElement`