# Remove all child nodes

Tags: javascript, dojo

How to remove all child nodes from `<div id="test"></div>` using Dojo or plain JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove all the children DOM elements in div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683366/remove-all-the-children-dom-elements-in-div)

Comment: This might help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401278/unregister-delete-all-child-nodes-of-a-div-tag-in-dojo

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`dojo.empty(node)` will remove all children from the node, while keeping the node.

`dojo.destroy(node)` will remove all children from the node, and then removes the node from its parent as well.

Comment: AMD - import dojo/dom-construct as domConstruct and then call domConstruct.empty(node) and domConstruct.destroy(node).

Answer (score 33):

While it is tempting to use el.innerHTML = "", and generally this works, a more correct approach would be:

```
var el = document.getElementById('test');
while( el.hasChildNodes() ){
    el.removeChild(el.lastChild);
}
```

The reason for this is because IE really hates table manipulation with innerHTML (this is documented somewhere in MSDN).

EDIT: found the MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532998%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#TOM_Create

Comment: I agree, cleaned this up a bit

Answer (score 9):

[here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/empty.html) is what you need:

`dojo.empty("someId");`

Answer (score 6):

```
document.getElementById('yourDivID').innerHTML="";
```

Comment: however, potentially dangerous. This will not work with tables in IE

Comment: no your not right i have tested with IE am able to remove all the child nodes from the Div.

Comment: I suspect you have not tested this completely. As reported by microsoft's own documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532998%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#TOM_Create): "_because of the specific structure required by tables, the innerText and innerHTML properties of the table and tr objects are read-only. To insert rows and cells, change the contents and attributes of the table, or resize table elements, you must use the DOM._" In other words, to rely on `el.innerHTML = ""` can be dangerous if you don't fully understand it.

Comment: Since Internet Explorer 9 you can use W3C DOM property textContent working with all major browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the W3C DOM property textContent as a replacement to Microsoft non-standard innerHTML/innerText, it's part of the DOM3 and supported by all major browsers including Internet Explorer since version 9 http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp

Update: innerHTML/innerText is now part of HTML5 standard